# onPress não chama metodo no React Native

Tags: react-native

Tenho um `TouchableOpacity` que ao tocar não chama o metodo `alert()` no react native, segue o meu código:

```
var data = []; export default class VerOs extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        isLoading: true,
        fontLoaded: false,
        listViewData: data
    };
    this.alerta = this.alerta.bind(this)
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.carregaList(this)
    this.alerta()

}


carregaList(that) {
    var newData = []
    FirebaseConfig.database().ref('/user').on('child_added', function (dat) {
        newData.push(dat)
        that.setState({
            listViewData: newData,
            isLoading: false
        })

    })
}


static navigationOptions = {
    tabBarLabel: 'Ver O.S',
    tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
        <Icon name='ios-aperture' color={tintColor} size={24} />
    )
}

alerta(){
    console.log("texto")
}

renderItem({ item }) {

    return (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.alerta} > //AQUI NÃO CHAMA
            <ListItem
                title={item.val().name}
                subtitle={item.val().name}
                leftAvatar={{ source: { uri: item.val().age } }} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
    )

}

render() {
    if (this.state.isLoading) {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <ActivityIndicator size="large" animating />
            </View>
        )
    } else {
        return (

            <Container>
                <Header>
                    <Left>
                        <Button transparent>
                            <Icon name='ios-menu' color={"#fff"} size={24} />
                        </Button>
                    </Left>
                    <Body>
                        <Title>Header</Title>
                    </Body>
                    <Right />
                </Header>
                <Content>
                    <FlatList
                        data={this.state.listViewData}
                        renderItem={this.renderItem} />

                </Content>
            </Container>

        )
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    }
});
```

Comment: Então, se tu abrir o debug no navegador tu vai ver teu `console.log` la, tudo certo com seu codigo, agora se você quer um alert na tela ai sugiro trocar o `console.log('texto)` por `alert('texto')`

Comment: Então o código está correto? No console também não aparece.

Comment: Então a forma como o onpress é usado sim, pode ser que haja problema em como é montado a lista no Flatlist, vou testar seu código para ver, daqui a pouco retorno.

Comment: Ok amigo vou verificar a fundo. Obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi depois de muita pesquisa.

Esse trecho:

```
renderItem({ item }) {...}
```

Mudei para:

```
renderItem = ({ item }) => {...}
```

E agora funciona, espero que ajude alguém ;-)

Comment: Agregaria muito a sua resposta se explicasse como descobriu como resolver. O porque precisa ser dessa forma.

Answer (score 1):

A solução é simples: se ao criar a função usar a forma funcao() {} e chamar o this dentro dela, esse this está referenciando apenas o escopo da classe da classe, ou seja, teria que ter uma função alerta dentro dessa função ou fazer um bind da função dentro do construtor.
Quando você chama funcao = () => {} o this fará referência a classe e aí sim vai chamar função alerta.
Eu não sei exatamente o porque disso, mas acredito que são as novas especificações do ECMAScript.